# face book login problem

Tags: facebook

I need your help.My requirement is when i login to my app it also login to the facebook and it can't be redirect to facebook,keeps in the app only.my app login username and password are equal to the facebook username and password.
Any help is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [their authentication support](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login)? It's standard [OAuth](http://oauth.net/2/).